# Is it possible to use xsd datatypes (e.g. xsd:string) and xml language attribute simultaneously in OWL2/RDF?

Tags: xml, types, xsd, rdf, owl

I'm using Protege 4.3 to create my OWL2 ontologies. Recently i mentioned that when adding the annotation property rdfs:label you can choose to define a datatype (e.g. xsd:string) or a language (xml:lang). But it is impossible to define both. If you choose a datatype, the language field is faded and vice versa.

This could be a Protege specific problem, but i wonder if OWL2 itself prohibits the use of datatype and language at the same time. I did some research but I couldn't find any document where this is explicitly mentioned. But i also couldn't find an example where it is done. Something like ...

```
<Class rdf:about="MyClass">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en" rdfs:Datatype="xsd:string">My special class</rdfs:label>
</Class>
```

... or ...

```
<http://example.org/AboutMe> ns0:gender "male"@en^^xsd:string .
```

I guess the above examples are not valid, but why?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this.  It's not a property of OWL, but of the underlying RDF.  From *Resource Description Framework (RDF): Concepts and Abstract Syntax*:

> #### [3.4 Literals](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#section-Literals)
>
> Literals are used to identify values such as numbers and dates by
>   means of a lexical representation. Anything represented by a literal
>   could also be represented by a URI, but it is often more convenient or
>   intuitive to use literals.
>
> A literal may be the object of an RDF statement, but not the subject
>   or the predicate.
>
> Literals may be **plain** or **typed**:
>
> - A [plain literal](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#dfn-plain-literal) is a string combined with an optional language tag. This may be used for plain text in a natural language. As recommended
>     in the RDF formal semantics [[RDF-SEMANTICS](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#ref-rdf-semantics)], these plain literals are
>     self-denoting.
> - A [typed literal](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#dfn-typed-literal) is a string combined with a datatype URI. It denotes the member of the identified datatype's value space obtained by
>     applying the lexical-to-value mapping to the literal string.

There's an upcoming new version of RDF, and in it, this is somewhat simplified.  There will be no more plain literals;  everything will have a datatype.  What used to be plain literals will be have the same lexical form, and will have datatype `xsd:string`.  A language tagged string will have the datatype `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#langString`. This is described in [3.3 Literals](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) of [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax: W3C Candidate Recommendation 05 November 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal).  It's possible that that document could change before it's accepted though, so if you use it as a reference, be sure to get the latest version.

Comment: Strange that it says "if and only if the datatype IRI is http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#langString, a non-empty language tag as defined […]". This prevents translation of literals using custom datatypes e.g. http://ns.ontowiki.net/SysOnt/Markdown .

Comment: @white_gecko I'm not sure I follow.  If you're using a custom datatype, then it won't be a rdf:langString, and thus won't have a language tag that is understood by pure RDF tools, but there's no reason that that custom datatype can't have its own language tag representation as part of its lexical form that tools that understand the datatype could handle.  What sort of translation would be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, contrary to what Joshua Taylor says in his answer, it is a property of the OWL 2 Structural specification. The relevant text in the OWL 2 specification is:

> *Literals* represent data values such as particular strings or integers. They are analogous to typed RDF literals [[*RDF Concepts*](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#ref-rdf-concepts)] and can also be understood as individuals denoting data values. Each literal consists of a lexical form, which is a string, and a datatype; the datatypes supported in OWL 2 are described in more detail in [Section 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Maps). A literal consisting of a lexical form `"abc"` and a datatype identified by the IRI `datatypeIRI` is written as `"abc"^^datatypeIRI`. Furthermore, literals whose datatype is *rdf:PlainLiteral* can be abbreviated in functional-style syntax ontology documents as plain RDF literals [[*RDF Concepts*](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#ref-rdf-concepts)]. These abbreviations are purely syntactic shortcuts and are thus not reflected in the structural specification of OWL 2. The observable behavior of OWL 2 implementation MUST be as if these shortcuts were expanded during parsing.

In OWL 2, there are no plain literals. So literals with language tags are in fact literals typed with `rdf:PlainLiteral` and the lexical form of such typed literals consists of a character string followed by `@` followed by the language tag.  Protégé simply allows to specify literals of type `rdf:PlainLiteral` by having separate fields for the character string and the language tag.  That functionality is specific to `rdf:PlainLiteral`, so it is normal that the language tag part is greyed out.

However, when an OWL 2 ontology is serialised to RDF, the serialisation uses RDF plain literals in place of a typed `rdf:PlainLiteral`. RDF literals are defined as Joshua said.

Now, the treatment of literals in [OWL 2 ontologies](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Ontologies) does not apply to [OWL 2 Full ontologies](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/#topic-ont-owl2full) (that is, RDF graphs) and therefore, OWL 2 Full ontologies can have true non-typed literals, and only these can have a language tag. But Protégé 4 is restricted to making OWL 2 ontologies, not OWL 2 Full ontologies.